# .NET Core 5 WinForms SystemMenu

Tags: winforms, .net-core, mono

How can I update the **SystemMenu** (the one that appears when we click on the icon in the top left of our window) in WinForms when using DotNet Core 5.0 in Linux?

[image]

Comment: @LexLi it is supported

Comment: @LexLi http://comfilewiki.co.kr/en/doku.php?id=comfilepi:running_.net_winforms_applications_with_mono:index

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Comment: You are way outdated. WinForms is supported as I have proof with various link and personally ported multiple WinForms projects to PI